# How can I indexing nested lists?

Tags: python, indexing, nested

When nested lists encountered in a class (more specifically, I should call it a multivariate function), can I use `__getitem__` method with two or more arguments?

I know it's not the typical usage of `__getitem__` and I should write it as a method of class, but I really want to take advantage of its `[]` feature.

Comment: It's really not atypical at all; numpy does it all the time.  `__getitem__` accepts a single argument; it _can_ be a tuple.  You'll just have to parse the tuple yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327313/overriding-getitem-for-a-nested-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not atypical at all; numpy does it all the time. `__getitem__` accepts a single argument; it can be a tuple. You'll just have to parse the tuple yourself.

```
class Indexer(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        pass
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            # do special processing for tuples here
            print(item)
        # Everyone likes the number 3, so make sure to return an extra 3.
        return [item, 3]
i = Indexer()

# this will print (2, 3), and got_item will have the value [(2, 3), 3]
got_item = i[2,3]

# This will print [(2, 3), 3]
print(got_item)
```

Obviously there's no real reason to return `[item, 3]`, but it just demonstrates that the code inside `__getitem__` can do whatever it wants.  You can return anything your heart desires.

Whenever the Python interpreter sees you index something (as in `i[2, 3]` in the code sample), the first thing it does is build a tuple out of the stuff between the square brackets.  You can check this by using the [dis](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html) module, which disassembles python code to see what the interpreter is really doing:

```
import dis
dis.dis('a[b, c]')

  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
              9 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you've never seen output from dis before, it can be a little confusing.  The important part is where it says `BUILD_TUPLE` **before** it says `BINARY_SUBSCR`.

That may be too much info: the important thing is that you can do whatever you want with `__getitem__`.

Comment: While I used to regard [2,3] as the  `__getitem__` has accepted two arguments!?

Answer (score 0):

`__getitem__` accepts as many arguments as you want, as they are packed as a tuple. See the following example, where the *nested list inside the class* is stored in `_data` and initialized using certain dimensions.

```
class Table(object):
    def __init__(self, dimx, dimy, initialize=0):
        self._dimx = dimx
        self._dimy = dimy
        self._data = [[initialize] * self._dimx] * self._dimy

    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        idx = args[0]
        return self._data[idx[0]][idx[1]]

    def __setitem__(self, *args):
        idx = args[0]
        self._data[idx[0]][idx[1]] = args[1]
```

With this class, you can simply perform the following:

```
t = Table(10, 1)
t[0, 1] = 'a'
print(t[0, 0])
print(t[0, 1])
```

... and it will yield:

```
0
a
```

Comment: `__getitem__` only accepts a _single_ argument; whenever you index something, Python builds a tuple out of everything within the square brackets.